# Need to Generate React Router's Link Component to HTML string or Alternative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript, vis.js

I am using the visjs.org javascript Timeline library.  You can provide the timeline with an array of objects which represent events on the timeline.  Each event has a content property which can be assigned a string or HTML.  I am wanting to provide anchor tags to this property.

I am using react-router and wanting to provide the HTML generated by react-router's  component for my anchor tags (***`currently I am just creating static HTML <a href="timeline/1">Item 1</a> which is a react-router route`***).

In my limited view, it appears that I need something similar to how ReactDom's renderToString function would work to generate the HTML string for this property.

Originally, I had a simple Timeline Container that passed the timeline event objects to a timeline component:

```
  return (
        <div>
            <Timeline timelineItems={ timelineItems }/>
        </div>
    );
```

and a simple Timeline Component that would utilize the vis.js timeline library to bind to a DOM element:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { timelineItems } = this.props;
    this.timeline = this.createTimeline(timelineItems);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div id = "timeline"> </div>
    );
}

createTimeline(items) {
    var container = document.getElementById("timeline");

    var data = new vis.DataSet(items);

    var options = {
        width: '100%',
        editable: true          
    };

    return new vis.Timeline(container, data, null, options);
}
```

But what I would like to do in the Timeline Container would be something like this where I pass each event item to an TimelineItem component:

```
        <div>
            <Timeline timelineItems={ timelineItems.map((item) => {
                let content = <TimelineItemComponent item={item}/>;
                return Object.assign({}, item, {content});
            }) }/>
        </div>
```

and the a TimelineItem Component returning the `<link>`:

```
class TimelineItemComponent extends React.Component{

  render() {
      const { item } = this.props;

      <div>
          <Link to={`timeline/${item.id}`}>{`The #${item.id}`}</Link>
      </div>
  }
}
```

OR forgo the additional TimelineItemComponent and just assign the `<Link to={`timeline/${item.id}`}>{`The #${item.id}`}</Link>` to the content property.

But obviously the problem is that these generate objects and the content property needs HTML (***again - like how ReactDom.renderToString works server side***).

Any thoughts how I can do that?

NOTE:  This is a universal app, so the original version is being rendered server side.

**UDPATE:**
If I use a standard anchor link that retains a dynamically created `href="timeline/1"` then it will cause the page to be completely rendered as well as a concatenation of the URL path for every link clicked.

For example, if selecting link with 'timeline/1' will update the URL path to /timeline/1 as expected.  But selecting another item on the list will update the path to /timeline/timeline/2

I want it to behave just as if I had added a  to the page which won't re-render the page.

Comment: If you just need a simple link anchor why not give a string "<a href....>" ?

Comment: Using a anchor link causes the entire page to refresh, but more importantly, on the second item selected, it concatenates the link to the existing URL path: (e.g. ../timeline/1/timeline/2  and so on...).

Comment: How did you fix it. I am looking for the same?